# How to convert a SQL Server database (including procedures, functions and triggers) to Firebird

Tags: sql-server, firebird

I am considering migrating to Firebird. To have a "quick start" approach I downloaded the trial of a conversion tool ([DBConvert](http://dbconvert.com/convert-firebird-to-mssql-pro.php)) and tried it.

I just picked up a random tool, this tool doesn't convert procedures, functions and triggers (I don't think it is a limit of the trial since there is not an explicit reference to sp, sf and triggers in the link above).

Anyway by trying that tool I had the message:

> The DB cannot be converted
>   successfully because some FK names are
>   too long.

This is because in some tables I have FK whose description is > 32 chars.

Is this a real Firebird limit or it is possible to overcome it somehow (of course renaming the FK is an extreme option because it is extra work)?

Anyway how to convert a SQL Server database fully to Firebird? Is there a valid tool? Did someone succeed in a conversion of non trivial databases?

Comment: @user193655, if `renaming the FK is an **extreme** option because it is **extra work**` then recoding by hand (which is most likely, unless there is some gee whiz program to do it for you, which I highly doubt) all the procedures, functions, and triggers, is going to kill you!

Comment: in my case I have many FK and relatively limited numbers of functions and procedures. Triggers are just there for customers where I made some extra customization. So writing them manually is maybe an option, but time = money so if a tool does 80% of the work instead of 60% I can consider using it.

Comment: Anyway with sp_rename it is quite easy to rename FK and indexes, so in principle it will not be too much painful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use some tools like [Interbase Datapump](http://www.clevercomponents.com/products/datapump/ibdatapump.asp) and you can also check [this](http://www.firebirdsql.org/manual/migration-mssql.html)

For size of FK : you have to rename them :(

You can also try to make this with [Database Worbench](http://www.upscene.com/products.dbw.index.php)

Comment: Database workbench trial helped me understand that I shuold also consider Postgresql, because probably the migration is smoother in that case. I will evaluate both. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I doubt you'll be able to just "convert" that all. Firebird/Interbase and Microsoft SQL Server use quite different data types, their SQL language dialect is somewhat different, and so forth.

You could probably get a 60-80% conversion - but the rest will always be manual effort that's needed.

If your conversion fails just because of those FK constraints: drop those in SQL Server before the conversion, and re-create them on the Firebird side after conversion.

Or: drop them in SQL Server and re-create them with shorter names, and then do the conversion.

Comment: Anyway you suggest to start with a tool and then manually fix the result?

Comment: if that tool can do a good chunk of the conversion - yes. Use the tool for as much as it can handle, and fine tune the rest manually.

Comment: You can use Database Workbench to do the tables, indices, constraints etc, it will automatically match the best datatypes and so on. Triggers, Stored Procedures are a different beast as the SQL that MS SQL Server uses is very different form Firebird, you need to convert those by hand.

Answer (score 0):

I know two more tools that might help you in the conversion.

The ESF Database Migration Toolkit 
[link text](http://www.easyfrom.net/)

and the DeZign for Databases 
[link text](http://www.datanamic.com/dezign/index.html)